# How to interactively plot graphs side by side from the UI by selecting the states from the checkboxGroup?

Tags: r, shiny

The data consist of US states, their construction types(character), variables Loss and Loss Cost for 2 models(i.e 4 factors) and their respective values(float). Construction Type will be on the X-axis, the loss cost will plot the Bar-Graph and the Loss will plot line-graph. The checkboxgroup should take the input from the user and plot four graphs  side by side in the order it is selected.

I have attempted to plot the graph but can't display it in the correct way.

Please assist

The code plots the list of graphs taking the input from the user. For Example: PLot 1, Plot2, PLot 3, Plot4 and Plot 5. If I select option 1,2,4,5 , it will leave a blank space for Plot 3 and plot the graphs in a column

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  headerPanel("Construction"),
  sidebarPanel(

    dropdownButton(label= "City", status = "default",width=400,tooltip = TRUE,circle = FALSE,

                   checkboxGroupInput("check","Check" ,choices = unique(raw$City), selected = NULL)),
    actionButton("plot","Display")

  ),

  mainPanel(

    lapply(1:length(unique(raw$City)), function(i)  {  
       plotOutput(paste0('plot',i))

    }
    )
  )
)



server <- function(input, output) {

  takinput <- reactive({

    a<- subset(raw, City %in% input$check)
    return(a)
  })

  plotlist <- lapply(1:length(unique(raw$City)), function(i)  { 

    output[[paste0('plot',i)]] <- renderPlot({

      input$plot 
      isolate(

        if(any(choice[i] %in% input$check)){

          b<- takinput()
          #View(b)
          ggplot(data = b,aes(x= Construction.Type, y= value,fill = variable)) +
            geom_bar(data = subset(b, variable %in%  c("RMS.AAL.per..Million","AIR.Loss.Cost.per..Million")
                                   & City == choice[i]) ,stat = 'sum' , position = "dodge", na.rm=TRUE)+

            guides(fill =  FALSE)+
            geom_line(data = subset(b, variable %in% c("RMS.Relative.AAL","AIR.Relative.Loss.Cost")
                                    & City == choice[i]), linetype = "dashed", 
                      aes(y = value*(1400/1.4),group =variable, colour= variable))+

            scale_color_manual(values =c("RMS.Relative.AAL" = "#7030A0","AIR.Relative.Loss.Cost" = "#FFC000")) +
            scale_fill_manual(values = c("#FFC000","#FFC000","#7030A0",'#7030A0'))+
            scale_y_continuous(name = expression("AAL Per Million"), sec.axis =sec_axis( ~.*1.4/1400, name = "Relative AAL"))+
            theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle= 25, vjust = 1.0,hjust = 1.0), legend.position = "none",
                  panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
                  panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line=element_line(colour = "black"))+ 
            labs(title= as.vector(choice[i]))+
            annotate(geom="text",x = c(4,4),y= c(1200,1140),label = c("RMS","AIR"))+
            annotate(geom="rect",xmin = c(3.3,3.3),xmax = c(3.7,3.7), ymin = c(1120,1180),ymax = c(1165,1225),
                     colour = c("#FFC000","#7030A0"), fill = c("#FFC000","#7030A0"))
        }

      )
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Expected Results: 4 Plots in 2 by 2 grid in the order of the input from the user

Actual results: The code plots the list of graphs taking the input from the user. For Example: PLot 1, Plot2, PLot 3, Plot4 and Plot 5. If I select option 1,2,4,5 , it will leave a blank space for Plot 3 and plot the graphs in a column.

Comment: Can someone please look into it?

Comment: need help...PLease look into it

Comment: What do you want to see if there are 2 plots selected ? 3 ? 5 ?